# Swapping GridView rows Up and Down?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hello guys I hope you can help me with this, I have a grid view and in each row I have an up and down button now each record has a sequence number (1, 2, 3..etc) what i want is when i click on the UP or Down the the rows will rearranged and the sequence number also accordingly, I searched for this but what I found didn't work for me, could you point me to some articles or give me an idea to help me solve this.

thanks a lot

Comment: `I searched for this but what I found didn't work for me` what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand">
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="btnUp" runat="server" 
                     CausesValidation="false" 
                     CommandName="Up" Text="↑" />
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="btnDown" runat="server" 
                     CausesValidation="false" 
                     CommandName="Down" Text="↓" />
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The snippet above will create a grid view with two columns, one for up arrow (Alt + 24) and one for down arrow (Alt + 25).

Now we need to write the code to handle the Up or Down command when the respective buttons are clicked, like this:

```
protected void gvQuestion_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       // Handle the Up command
       if (e.CommandName == "Up")
       {
           // Do logic to move the row up (most likely decrements a sort order value)

           // Rebind grid
       }

       // Handle the Down command
       if (e.CommandName == "Down")
       {
           // Do logic to move the row down (most likely increments a sort order value)

           // Rebind grid
       }
}
```

The List object that populates the grid view will need to have a Sort value (int) or have the value persisted in the database so that it can be retrieved and updated when rows are moved up or down.